# Forgot to add tick marks in Checklist - UK Visitor Visa

Tags: uk

I submitted my standard visitor visa (6 months) application today, but I think I forgot to put tick marks in the three boxes under "Please tick the following boxes to confirm you understand the application process." I am also not sure if the VFS counter executive ticked the boxes on my behalf while checking the application. Will this lead to a refusal? I am tensed!

Answer (score 2):

From this and your earlier question it is likely you did everything correctly and are just stressed. In any case all you can do now is wait for the outcome.

Comment: Indeed, the checklist requirement is a guideline for the applicant and is not required for visa processing. I have received a UK visa without handing in the checklist.